# A US citizen, working part time in Ireland, some earnings on Amazon.com. What to do about my US tax obligations

Tags: united-states, taxes, irs, non-resident, form-1040x

I am a US citizen living & working in Ireland. I pay Irish tax on my wages. I also earn some pocket money selling on Amazon.com. What should I do about my Amazon.com income with respect to the IRS? How should I file that in the US? Is there an exemption I can claim as it is less than $1000?

Comment: You *are* and have been declaring all your income from everywhere on your annual IRS filing, right?

Answer (score 1):

You should add it to all the other income and continue paying taxes as you would on your Irish salary. That is true for both the US and the Irish sides of the equation.

In case you didn't know - your Irish earnings are taxable in the US, since the US taxes **all** of your income. Your Amazon.com earnings are taxable in Ireland since that's where you earned it. You can use the FEIE/FTC as appropriate on your US tax return to reduce your tax *liability*, but **all** of your income should be reported.